# Generate scss multiple css class*

Tags: css, sass

I have the following css helper classes. So my question is, is there better way to do that? or can i generate such a classes in scss to make it cleaner and better.

Thanks.

```
.m-1 { margin: 1px !important; }
.m-2 { margin: 2px !important }
.m-3 { margin: 3px !important }
.m-4 { margin: 4px !important }
.m-5 { margin: 5px !important }
.m-6 { margin: 6px !important }
.m-7 { margin: 7px !important }
.m-8 { margin: 8px !important }
.m-9 { margin: 9px !important }
.m-10 { margin: 10px !important }
```

Comment: While it has nothing to do with your question: you should check if it is really necessary to use `!important`. Sometimes there is no easy way to avoid it, but you should first try to find a way to not use it, because in many cases this will make more problems that it would solve, especially with such a helper class.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @t.niese23 that wasn't an answer on my question.  But thanks any way.

Comment: @cimmanon am new to scss and have no idea how to handle such a thing, so this why I asked.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_7)

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
   .m-#{$i} { margin: 1px * $i !important; }
}
```

Comment: appreciate your time,  that's what I was looking for.  Thanks

Comment: yep is there any possibility to increment 5 values during loop. instead of incrementing single steps increment 5's steps 0 5 10 15 like this

Comment: @Vikranth You can use math with for cycle, like `@for $I from 0 through 3` and multiply by 5, when necessary. Or you can use `$I = 0; @while $I < 20 { $I = $I + 5; } `